# Find the orthogonal complement of $U$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let
$$V:=\{f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; f \text{ is continuous} \}$$
and consider the inner product
$$
\langle f, g\rangle:=\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) d x
$$
Let us consider the subspace of $V$:
$$
U:=\{f \in V ; f(0)=0\}
$$
What is the orthogonal complement of $U$?

**My attempt.**
Let $g$ be a function in $V$ such that $\langle g, f\rangle = 0$ for all $f$ in $U$. In other words, $g$ is orthogonal to every function in $U$.

For any function $f$ in $U$, we have $f(0) = 0$. I think that $g(x)$ is independent of the specific properties of $f(x)$, and that $f(0) = 0$ does not add any information in this picture. This means that the integral defining $\langle g, f\rangle$ should be zero for any function $f$ in $U$.

Then we can conclude that $g(x)$ must be identically zero on the interval $[0,1]$ in order to satisfy the condition $\int_0^1 g(x) f(x) dx = 0$ for all $f$ in $U$:
$$
U^\perp = \{0\}
$$
This also gives and exampe of the fact that $U^{\perp \perp}$ could be different from $U$ because in this case $U^{\perp \perp}=V$. Am I right?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your intuition is correct about $U^{\perp} = \{0\}$. Suppose that $g(x) \in U^{\perp}$. Then $xg(x)\in U$ and we must have
$$(xg(x),g(x)) = 0 \implies \int_0^1xg(x)^2\,dx = 0$$
Since $xg(x)^2 \geq 0$ for all $x$ we are forced to conclude $xg(x)^2 = 0$ for all $x$ which is to say $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why does $g(x)\in U^{\perp}$ imply that $xg(x)\in U$?

Comment: $h(x) = xg(x)$ has $h(0) = 0 \cdot g(0) = 0$, so $h \in U$

Comment: Ah ofcourse. Lol. Pardon my blindness.

Comment: @Lely $U^{\perp\perp}$ is obviously $V$ as $\int 0\cdot f=0$ for all $f\in V$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $g\in U^{\perp}$ . Then $\int g(x)f(x)\,dx=0$ for all $f\in U$.

Now consider a sequence of continuous functions $f_{n}$ in $U$ such that $f_{n}\to g$ pointwise. Then as $g$ is continuous, you can choose your sequence such that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_{n}(x)|<M$ for all $n$ for some $M$.

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_{[0,1]}g^{2}(x)\,dx$ due to Dominated Convergence Theorem.

But $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}(x)g(x) =0$ for all $n$.

This gives that $\int_{[0,1]}g^{2}(x)\,dx=0$ which means that $g(x)=0$ almost everywhere. But as $g$ is continuous, we have that $g=0$ identically. So $U^{\perp}=\{0\}$

One way to construct $f_{n}$ is as follows. Consider $f_{k}(x)=\begin{cases} g(x)\,,x\in [\frac{1}{k},1]\\ 0, x\in[0,\frac{1}{2k}]\\ (x-\frac{1}{2k})2kg(\frac{1}{k})\,\,,x\in[\frac{1}{2k},\frac{1}{k}]\end{cases}$ .

That is, we are just restricting the function to equal $g$ in $[\frac{1}{k},1]$ and $0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2k}]$ and we join linearly in between.