# Why for infinite dimensional spaces $\left(W^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}$ could be different from $W$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The orthogonal complement of a line $W$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is the plane perpendicular to it, $W^{\perp}$; but in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is also true that the orthogonal complement of the plane $W^{\perp}$ is the straight line $W$. Hence we see that $\left(W^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=W$, ie that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of a vector subspace is equal to the subspace itself. This is only true if the spaces are finite dimensional.

If spaces are not finite dimensional, many examples exist which demonstrate that this may not be true. E.g.: [Find the orthogonal complement of $U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716606/find-the-orthogonal-complement-of-u). I apologize if my question may seem naive, but: why for infinite dimensional spaces $\left(W^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}$ could be different from $W$? As said, counterexamples can be found to answer this question, but what I would like to know is if there is a simple and intuitive reason why $\left(W^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}$ could be different from $W$.

Comment: $W \subset (W^{\perp})^{\perp}$ holds in infinite dimensional spaces as well. So, the problem arises when we prove the other inclusion. Perhaps it doesn't give you the intuitive idea that you are looking for, but when you study the proof of that other inclusion, you use the finiteness of a basis.

Comment: $W^{\perp\perp}$ is the (topological) closure of $W$. So, your question really amounts to "why are some subspaces not closed?".

Comment: There are some great rigorous explanations below. But intuitively, there is just too much "space" in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't fully understand what kind of answer you are expecting, but here is a topological  explanation.

Let $E=$ be a real vector space with an inner product.

Let $w\in E$. Then the map $x\in E\mapsto x\cdot w\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (because of Cauchy Schwarz inequality).

Hence the set of $x\in E$ such that $x\cdot w=0$ is closed (for the topology induced by the norm induced by the inner productà. As an intersection of  closed sets is closed, it follows that for any subspace $W$, $W^\perp$ is closed. Consequently, $(W^\perp)^\perp$ is also closed, and a necessary condition for having $(W^\perp)^\perp=W$ is that $W$ is closed.

Note that if $W$ is finite dimensional, it is necessarily closed so you have no obstruction (in particular, if $E$ is finite dimensional)

You may check that also counter examples you can find are using non closed subspaces.

Answer (score 4):

In real or complex inner-product spaces (e.g., Hilbert spaces) of arbitrary dimension, $(W^\perp)^\perp$ is (provably) the topological closure of $W$. So $W$ is strictly smaller than $(W^\perp)^\perp$ exactly when $W$ is not closed.

In finite-dimensional spaces, every subspace is closed, but in infinite-dimensional spaces there are many, many not-closed subspaces. For example, in a Hilbert space with orthonormal (Hilbert-space) basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots$, the subspace consisting of *finite* linear combinations of the $e_j$'s is dense in the space, but is not the whole space (e.g., it omits $\sum_j e_j/j$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $H=\ell^2(\Bbb{N}^+, \Bbb{C})$ the Hilbert space of square summable sequences.  $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ its standard orthonormal basis.

Let $V=\operatorname{span}\{\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty\}$.  ($V$ is the subspace of all sequences with finite support.)  $V$ is an incomplete inner-product space which is dense in $H$.

Let $x_0 = \sum_{j=1}^\infty e_j/j\in H\setminus V$.  Let $\phi: H\to \Bbb{C}$ be the bounded linear functional $\phi(u) = \langle u, x_0\rangle$.  Then $\phi\rvert_V$ is a bounded non-zero linear functional on $V$.  Let $W=\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)\cap V = \{x_0\}^\perp \cap V$.  Then $W$ is a proper closed subspace of $V$ of co-dimension $1$.  Let $N=W^\perp \cap V$ be the relative orthogonal complement of $W$ in $V$.

Claim: $N = \{0\}$.  So $N^\perp \cap V = V$.  ($N^\perp \cap V$ is the relative double orthogonal complement of $W$ in $V$.)

Proof:  Assume by contradiction there is a $v_0\in N$ such that $v_0\ne 0$.  Then $v_0\perp W$, and since $W$ has codimension $1$ in $V$, $V = W \oplus \operatorname{span}\{v_0\}$.  It is not possible that $\langle x_0, v_0 \rangle = 0$, because then $x_0\perp V$ and since $V$ is dense in $H$ this implies that $x_0 = 0$ - a contradiction.  So $\langle x_0, v_0 \rangle\ne 0$.

Now let
$$v_1 = \frac{\langle x_0, v_0 \rangle}{\|v_0\|^2} v_0$$
Then $v_1 \perp W$ because $v_1$ is a (non-zero) scalar multiple of $v_0$.  Furthermore
$$
\begin{align}
\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle &= \frac{|\langle x_0, v_0\rangle|^2}{\|v_0\|^4} \|v_0\|^2 = \frac{|\langle x_0, v_0\rangle|^2}{\|v_0\|^2}\\
\langle v_1, x_0\rangle &= \frac{\langle x_0, v_0 \rangle}{\|v_0\|^2} \langle v_0, x_0\rangle = \frac{|\langle x_0, v_0\rangle|^2}{\|v_0\|^2}\end{align}
$$
So $\langle u, v_1\rangle = \langle u, x_0\rangle = 0$ for all $u\in W$ and $\langle v_1, v_1\rangle = \langle v_1, x_0\rangle$.  It follows that $\langle u, v_1\rangle = \langle u, x_0\rangle$ for all $u\in W\oplus\operatorname{span}\{v_1\} = V$.  Since $V$ is dense in $H$ this implies that $v_1 = x_0$.  But $v_1\in V$ and $x_0\not\in V$ - a contradiction.